# what does calling this function twice do?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui

I found this code over the net. What I don't get is what does this last line do.

```
jQuery("#ID").autocomplete("option", "delay", 100)
```

the code seems to work without this line too.

I am new to jquery, so please pardon if this seems silly.

```
jQuery(function () 
 {
      jQuery("#ID").autocomplete({
          source: function (request, response) {
           jQuery.getJSON(
               "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q="+request.term,
               function (data) {
                response(data);
               }
           );
          },
          minLength: 3,
          select: function (event, ui) {
           var selectedObj = ui.item;
           jQuery("#ID").val(selectedObj.value);
           return false;
          }

      });
      jQuery("#id_ccity").autocomplete("option", "delay", 100);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: The function isn't being declared twice it's being called twice. Pretty important difference.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call instantiates the plugin for use on the `#ID` element.

The second call is setting the `delay` option to a value of `100` on the `#id_ccity` element.

Note that for the second call to work, the plugin has to be instantiated first. I assume this is done elsewhere in your code, otherwise you will receive an error.

Comment: It depends on how the plugin has been coded to accept the parameters passed to it. You do not get this behaviour by default.

Comment: Ok, got it. basically we are setting the delay for refreshes between the get call.. right?

Comment: will need to take a look at the JS then. anyhow for now how I understand is that they just initialize a static or global timeout which is shared for the object.

Comment: This code is working fine for me as it is. Have I not initialized it first with the JS shorthand? I mean JQuery(function)?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` always needs one or more DOM element to work with.when we define -

```
jQuery("#elementId")
```

- it will search for an element with `id = "elementId"`. you can also use `classname` assisgned to that element or the tag of the element. like -

  jQuery("input")

so -

```
jQuery("#ID").autocomplete(initializations)
```

for element with `id = "ID"` and

```
jQuery("#id_ccity").autocomplete(initializations)
```

for element with `id = "id_ccity"`.

Comment: uh.. I already know that and got that. I was confused about calling the function twice. First with the geobyte api as argument and next with the delay. Answer#1 explained it nicely.

Comment: ohk... :) and plz if u got the answer then accept Answer#1. :)

Comment: Ya, apparently I cannot do that for sometime.